# Convert string date format to timestamp for storing into firebase Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

Until now I was managing all of my customer data (about 8k clients) in MySQL db through http request from my Flutter app. I've been saving client registration date as a strin in `dd.mm.YY` format e.g. 12.12.2021.

Recently I decide to switch to Firestore where I can set new clients `'date_added': Timestamp.now(),`. I have set up mechanism where if app detects client from previous sql db, I want to be able to convert that string `date_added` to save to Firestore timestamp format.

[image]

I am not sure how to achieve it as new to Flutter. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got this working:

`import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';`

```
DateTime convertedDateTime = DateTime.parse('2022-01-10 00:00:00');
Timestamp convertedDateTimeStamp = Timestamp.fromDate(convertedDateTime);
// convertedDateTimeStamp is what was needed
```